# Как правильно получить стак фрагментов и его последовательность?

Tags: android, android-fragment

В общем задача такая

Есть 3 фрагмента, которые можно открыть в 3х последовательностях

1) `1 -> 2 -> 3` ,

а можно так

2) `1 -> 3 -> 2`

или так

3) `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3`

Вопрос вот в чем, во фрагменте 3 есть кнопка которая открывает фрагмент 2 и условие такое если под фрагментом 3 в бекстаке уже есть фрагмент 2 (как указано в последовательности 1), то нужно просто сделать 3му фрагменту `popBackStack()` и таким образом нам откроется нужный нам фрагмент 2

А есть такой флоу если под фрагментном 3 в бекстаке нет фрагмента 2 (как указано в последовательности 2), то нужно создать фрагмент и через `beingTransaction()` открыть его.

**Как это сделать?**

Нужно при нажатии на кнопку в 3м фрагменте посмотреть есть ли в бекстаке фрагмент 2 и является ли он предыдущим фрагментом или находится через один и в зависимости от этого делать либо `popBackStack()` либо через транзакцию открыть его.

**Проблема**

Я не могу посмотреть, что есть у меня в бекстек. Метод `fragManager.getBackStackEntryCount()` возвращает мне верное значение (3 в моем случае), но это только количество фрагментов я не могу знать что это за фрагменты.

А метод `fragManager.getFragments()` возвращает мне только последний добавленный фрагмент.

выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делаю не так? Как по мне это достаточно тривиальная задача... Проверить, что есть в бекстеке.

**P.S.** 
Добавление фрагментов делаю вот так

```
getSupportFragmentManager()//
                 .beginTransaction()//
                 .replace(R.id.fl_main_Container, MyFragment.newInstance(false), MyFragment.TAG)//
                 .addToBackStack(null)//
                 .commit();//
```

**EDIT**

Мне нужно знать не только есть ли фрагмент в стаке (`findFragByTag()`), мне так же нужно знать в какой последовательности он там

То есть по сути мне очень подходит метод `fragManager.getFragments()` который мне возвращает и фрагменты и их последовательность. Но в моем случае он всегда возвращает только последний(как видно на скришоте)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Искать фрагменты в `BackStack` можно по их тэгу, если вы его устанавливаете в транзакции добавления фрагмента.

```
Frgament fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_TO_SEARCH);
if (fr == null) {
   //не найдено
} else {
   //найдено
}
```

**UPD**

Согласно доке вы не сможете получить последовательность фрагментов в `backstack` методом `getFragments()`, если используете `replace`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#getFragments()

> Get a list of all fragments that are currently added to the
>   FragmentManager. This may include those that are hidden as well as
>   those that are shown. This will not include any fragments only in the
>   back stack, or fragments that are detached or removed.
>
> The order of the fragments in the list is the order in which they were
>   added or attached.

Таким образом вашу задачу можно решить так (недавно так делал и оно работает):

1. Создать список строк-тэгов
2. В процессе добавления/удаления фрагмента добавлять/удалять тэг из списка
3. Получать наличие и последовательность фрагментов в стэке через список тэгов.
4. Этот список надо сохранять при смене конфигурации (`onSaveInstanceState`)

Comment: Я не правильно сформулировал вопрос. Внес правку. Мне так же нужно знать последовательность. Не только его наличие в бекстеке

Comment: Потому, что может быть такая ситуация когда фрагменты открыты вот так `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3` и тогда `popBackStack()` не поможет, так как нужно открыть фрагмент 2...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, обновил ответ, возможно он поможет)

Comment: Типо сделать какой то `List` и в `BaseFragment` в `onAttach()` добавлять и в `onDetach()` удалять? И список этот по хорошему должен быть синглтоном или сидеть в `App` , так?

Comment: Ну, в моём случае был фрагмент (A), в который добавлялись другие фрагменты (B,C,D etc). Список был в А, в нём же были методы для открытия фрагментов и именно в этих методах в список добавлялось/удалялось что-то. B,C,D etc не должны знать о том как они используются и что-то куда-то наверх отправлять по иерархии)